# silverlight: How to pass a value from an item in a listbox by clicking a button beside the item

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, relaycommand, commandparameter

I have a Listbox, shows an item and a delete button beside it. How can i trigger the relay command passing a parameter to the viewmodel so i can execute the deletion.

Sample code.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentUserRoles, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="Id" Name="lstRoles" Grid.Row="0" >
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                     <Button Command="{Binding Path=RemoveFromUserRolesCommand, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Delete">
                     </Button>
                     <TextBlock Text="  "></TextBlock>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

View Model:

```
        private RelayCommand _removeFromUserRolesCommand = null;
        public RelayCommand RemoveFromUserRolesCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_removeFromUserRolesCommand == null)
                {

                    _removeFromUserRolesCommand = new RelayCommand(
                        () => this.OnARemoveFromUserRolesCommand(),
                        () => (this._adminModel != null) );
                }
                return _removeFromUserRolesCommand;
            }
        }
        private void OnARemoveFromUserRolesCommand()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!_adminModel.IsBusy && SelectedAvailableRole != null)
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               ...
            }
        }
```

But it doesn't work. Im new to Silverlight so anybody experienced this kind of scenario? Can you Share?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a separate ViewModel for each one of the items of your list. Inside you store the ID of the element. Then you put the RemoveCommand inside those ViewModel and perform the deletion there using the ID.